# How to detect OpenGl version at run time. Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

How can I detect witch openGl version my device is running? All what I found is android saying that all devices 2.3+ support openGL 2.0. Witch is not true as I found devices that been upgraded to version 2.3 but they system doesn't support it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glGetString(GL_VERSION)`

See more at: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glGetString.html

Comment: If GL10 class is used, 1.1 is on the string, if OpenGL Es version is 3.0, results can confuse users.

Answer (score 5):

From the Android CTS's (Compatibility Test Suite) [OpenGlEsVersionTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/graphics/src/android/opengl/cts/OpenGlEsVersionTest.java):

```
private static int getVersionFromPackageManager(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    FeatureInfo[] featureInfos = packageManager.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    if (featureInfos != null && featureInfos.length > 0) {
        for (FeatureInfo featureInfo : featureInfos) {
            // Null feature name means this feature is the open gl es version feature.
            if (featureInfo.name == null) {
                if (featureInfo.reqGlEsVersion != FeatureInfo.GL_ES_VERSION_UNDEFINED) {
                    return getMajorVersion(featureInfo.reqGlEsVersion);
                } else {
                    return 1; // Lack of property means OpenGL ES version 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/** @see FeatureInfo#getGlEsVersion() */
private static int getMajorVersion(int glEsVersion) {
    return ((glEsVersion & 0xffff0000) >> 16);
}
```

It actually provides a few other ways as well and the test verifies that they all return the same results.