# Android Maps API requires openGL es 2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

**The Maps v2 documentation states:**

> Because version 2 of the Google Maps Android API requires OpenGL ES
>   version 2, you must add a `<uses-feature>` element as a child of the
>   `manifest` element in AndroidManifest.xml:
>
> ```
> <uses-feature   
>    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"  
>    android:required="true"/>`
> ```
>
> This notifies external services of the
>   requirement. In particular, it has the effect of preventing Google
>   Play Store from displaying your app on devices that don't support
>   OpenGL ES version 2.

In fact, it throws an `exception` if this is not in the manifest. I don't want to filter my app in the store, I plan to keep using the old maps for old devices, and only show the new maps if the required features are present, detected at runtime rather than before installation.

So how do I do that? Does it have to be something like multiple `APKs` with different `manifests`?

Comment: Just android:required="false". Then it should not be filtered.

Comment: `android:required="false"` results in `12-05 22:18:31.484: E/AndroidRuntime(9618): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Google Maps Android API only supports OpenGL ES 2.0 andabove. Please add <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" /> into AndroidManifest.xml
` on a Nexus S 4.1.2

Comment: Same issue here, if I remove the requirement from the manifest (or set required="false") the MapFragment throws an exception on a device which does support OpenGL ES 2.0.  It's as if the MapFragment is looking for the requirement in the activity service configuration rather than checking if the device itself has support for OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Final Update**

As of 2013/12/20, the [Android Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) shows that approximately 100% of devices now support OpenGL 2.0+ so this answer is no longer relevant. You may simply require OpenGL ES 2.0+ in your manifest.

**Update**

This is fixed as of rev 7 of the Google Play Services SDK add-on. It is safe to use `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false"/>` and to [detect OpenGL ES 2.0 at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15215529/115145).

**Original answer**

It appears that the Google Maps Android API v2 requires an explicit `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true/>` declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml` so there is no way to deploy Google Maps Android API v2 services without excluding all OpenGL ES 1.x devices.  At the time of this writing, [Google's Android Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL) shows that, among 1.1 and 2.0 devices, 90.8% of devices support 2.0.

On a particular device (Motorola XOOM), this code results in `supportsEs2 = true`:

```
// Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;
```

However, when there is no `<uses-feature>` declaration in the manifest, MapFragment is throwing a RuntimeException:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Google Maps Android API only supports OpenGL ES 2.0 andabove. Please add <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" /> into AndroidManifest.xml
    at maps.y.ae.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.y.bu.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.y.p.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.c$4.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.c.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    ... 22 more
```

Here's to hoping that an update to the Maps library will remove this limitation so we can deploy a single APK and use runtime APIs to determine whether or not to load the new Google Maps v2 experience or fall back to another compatible solution.

Comment: This issue is tracked here : http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4699

Don't forget to star the issue, in the hopes that it will get noticed. As of dec 2012, there are only 7 votes.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed and will be release with next release of Maps Android API as mentioned in [issue #4699](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4699#c4)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, looked around and most of the suggested workaround for the emulator didn't work for me. Then i found a post were the [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator was suggested. This emulator supports OpenGL ES version 2. It is also much faster than the standard emulator.