# Application is not visible on tablet android

Tags: android, tablet, google-play

My application is not visible for tablets and I dont know why. I have added Camera Permission in last update but its not even showing for the tablets those who have camera. I tried on [Dell venu 7](http://www.gsmarena.com/dell_venue_7-5751.php) Here is my permission set

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
        android:name="com.example.dummy.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <!-- Urban airship -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <!-- Push Notification Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Urban airship -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.dummy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Urban airship -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.dummy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Add this in ur manifest. <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />.

Comment: Some tablets have no camera options. So this permission is given in manifest.

Comment: @Alliswell Dell venu has the camera. Then why its not showing it in play store?

Comment: Just wanted to get this cleared, was it showing for tablets before adding that permission?

Comment: @user2450263 yes it was.

Comment: its not the problem ur device having camera or not. But we use camera function for tablet i think this permission is required.

Comment: @Alliswell  so solution would be i need to make android:required="false". Will it not crash on devices those who dont have camera?

Comment: @user2450263 Its not duplicate. I have seen that post. That post has screen compatible-screens mode. There is big difference here if you don't specify it.

Comment: ok not a possible duplicate but for the camera permission problem, take a look at the [second answer on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play) , the app not crashing part will need to be handled by code also

Comment: @user2450263 Thanks for it man.I will add check manually

Comment: @Manoj Have u published the updated app?

Comment: @IamDeveloper no not yet. Will update it soon.

Comment: @IamDeveloper hey app is not visible on some phones also. with these permission set.

Comment: @user2450263 Phone is Hdpi 480X800 and 4.1.2 Jelly bean

Comment: @Manoj check the  <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" /> --has been declared twice, and maps should work with required=false too, had that in my app, similar problem of devices, [refer this link for exact explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714484/android-maps-api-requires-opengl-es-2)