# Android: Is it possible to use Google Maps API on emulator?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use Google Maps API on emulator but I'm struggling with it. 
I already set up the API key (I set the package name and SHA-1 on Google console as well) but this error happens.

Here is `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

> Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

Seems like Nexus 5 cannot be used for the Google Maps API on emulator because Emulated Performance is needed to specify to use the Google Maps API.

So I tried to use Nexus 4 instead because I can specify Emulated Performance: Graphics for the device but this error happens on the display.

> This App won't run until you update Google Play Services.

I looked up this error and all the answers to this error are kind of old so I cannot understand how I can configure it correctly.

How can I fix these errors?
Has anyone beeen successful in using the API on emulator recently?

Comment: you have check in a realdevice

Comment: You should log into playstore and update the google play services. or Download the latest android system image with google play services included from sdk or when creating a emulator.

Answer (score 2):

When creating Virtual device only select device which has play store else play services won't be available . The latest of all is Pixel 2 so I would suggest using it

[image]

Comment: But all the devices which can use Play Store cannot specify Emulated Performnace: Graphics and the first error happens.

Comment: @ani for me pixel 2 worked fine and maps are being shown

Comment: Google Maps API doesn't work for me even when I leave all settings to Android Studio. The error log says `Couldn't connect to Google API client: otb{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}` but I'm sure API is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the google map api. Seems like that device is missing google play service and/or might be running at a out of scope api level. The emulator I use without a problem is a Pixel XL. Try that emulator or at least make sure the new emulator shows it has google play services

Comment: I tried to use Pixel Xl but the same error happens. `This App won't run until you update Google Play Services.`

Comment: Do any of your available devices have the google play service icon? Is everything up to date?

Comment: You mean play store icon? Some of the devices like Pixel or Nexus can use it but these devices cannot specify Emulated Performance.

Comment: When you go to create an emulator do you see something like the play store icons on the first image on https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

Comment: Yes. But the devices which have the icon cannot sepficy Emulated Performance. How can you use Google Play Service on Pixel XL?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13729209/3670439. If that doesn’t work I’m not sure, and I apologize.