# How to detect which Opengl-es version is supported by a device

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

How can I detect which version of Opengl-es is supported by a specific device? I am interested to check it during the initialization of my custom SurfaceGlView

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684918/how-to-detect-opengl-version-at-run-time-android